# ZipArchive doesn't make a archive

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

ZipArchive doen't create archive at all!
I tried:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive($this->name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);

$zip = new ZipArchive($this->name, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($this->name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($this->name, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);
```

but all doesn't create an archive and return true!
If I try to creat file with fopen it normally works so it's not a permissions problem

Some ideas?

Comment: have you actually tried putting anything into this zip archive? I believe that until you actually attacha  file to it, the zip file exists purely in memory only.

Comment: yes, i tried and addEmptyDir or addFile returns true too

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to call `$zip->close()`

Also I can't recall if it creates the file if you don't add anything to it (your question doesn't say whether or not you did that).

Comment: +1 It is *very* important to explicitly close writers/streams; in the case of a ZIP archive there is a checksum that must be added to the end which is why a `close` (read: "end adding files") is required.